# Unable to disable scroll function when resizing window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two menus that fade in and out on scroll. But when I resize the window I want to stop this event. I've tried plenty of stuff, searched a lot but nothing worked. I'm missing something. Here's what I have:

```js
var scrollHandler = $(window).scroll(function() {
  var top = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (top > 0) {
    $('.menu').fadeOut('fast', function() {
      $('.second-menu').fadeIn('fast');
    });
  } else {
    $('.second-menu').fadeOut('fast', function() {
      $('.menu').fadeIn('fast');
    });
  }
})

scrollHandler;

if ($(window).width() < 768) {
  $(window).off("scroll", scrollHandler);
}
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$(window).width()` is **only evaluated at runtime** (i.e. the width of the viewport when the script is executed). It is not reactive in the sense that it will be updated on-the-fly when the viewport is resized.

Therefore, if you want to listen to changes in the width, you will have to place the logic within the window resize event callback:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    $(window).off('scroll');
  }
});
```

Moreover, there are several issues with your code.

1. The `scrollHandler` should reference/define the function, *not* the outcome of the binding
2. Calling `scrollHandler` does not do anything. If you make the changes as per #1, then you can simply bind the logic using `$(window).on('scroll', scrollHandler);`
3. The `.off()` method does not accept a second parameter, this is enough: `$(window).off('scroll')`

After refactoring, your code will look something like this:

```
var scrollHandler = function() {
  var top = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (top > 0) {
    $('.menu').fadeOut('fast', function() {
      $('.second-menu').fadeIn('fast');
    });
  } else {
    $('.second-menu').fadeOut('fast', function() {
      $('.menu').fadeIn('fast');
    });
  }
};

// Bind scrollHandler firing to scroll event
$(window).on('scroll', scrollHandler);


$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    $(window).off('scroll');
  }
});
```

---

### Note:

If you want to get the best performance out of this, you should throttle the resize event so that the callback function is not fired too frequently. [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#throttle)/[Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) have utility functions for that (`_.throttle()`), and there is also a [jQuery plugin available](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce).

In Lodash/Underscore.js:

```
$(window).resize(_.throttle(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    $(window).off('scroll');
  }
}, 100));
```

Using Ben Alman's jQuery plugin:

```
$(window).resize($.throttle(100, function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    $(window).off('scroll');
  }
}));
```

Comment: @Mellville See updated answer. There are issues with your code that has to be fixed.

Comment: great, it worked, and thanks so much for the complete answer :)